# Can a pawn move to the last row diagonally without a capture?

Tags: rules, pawns, pawn-promotion

Playing the "Champion" J2ME chess, I noticed that the bot (black) made the move "Pg2-h1=Q." Is this a bug or just a rarely known rule like en passant and castling?

Comment: It is a bug, pawns only go diagonally when they capture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pawns only go diagonally when they capture. See the section 3.7 of [Chess rules](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article).

The software you mention probably has a flaw.

Answer (score -2):

Not a bug, it's an entirely possible move. (at least on chess titans.) Chess titans is the windows 7 version of chess.

Comment: I don't think what happens in Chess titans is relevant to what happens in "Champion" J2ME chess. It's the rules of chess that matter, I'd say.